# How to install app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I made simple application for iphone and i am able to run it on simulator but i am not able to install it on my iPhone device for testing purpose. When I tried to run it on iphone device it giving me the error as :

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any
>   valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Can any buddy help me what are the steps I need to follow to install it in my iPhone ?

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: first chk your certificate in keychain

Comment: you make new Certificate in Keychain and after use it

Comment: Check your provisioning profile is valid or not

Comment: Do i need to create a certificate for it ? I am totally new to this please suggest

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

Comment: yes check the status in Provision profile valid or not?

Comment: @YakubMoriswala, Do you have a provisioning profile? Check this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html

Comment: ACB when I am trying to open iOS Provisioning portal http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action it gives me error 'Access denied'.

Comment: Do I require to enroll in iOS Developer Program ?

Comment: Yes, of course.. Then only you can use device for testing. Either you or your company should have a valid profile to start iOS development.

Comment: Thanks ACB for clarify all the things...:)

Comment: Just to confirm again If want to test application created by me and I want to install it only on my iphone still this enrollment($99) is required ?

Comment: yes buddy it is necessary to enroll for $99 minimum to test any application on device

Comment: @YakubMoriswala, Yes. I have added that as an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer.

You need to have a valid provisional profile for testing in your device. Either you or your company needs to have it. For more details check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html). You are getting this error message because you dont have a provisional profile associated with your device and project.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have selected right Provisional profile in your Xcode-code signing identity.

Comment: How to check provisioning profile ? If there is no any provisioning profile do I need to create this ?

Comment: go to the Organizer and select Device and see the provisioning profile

Comment: Virja I am not able to open iOS Provisioning portal. It gives me Access Denied. Do I required to enroll in iOS Developer program ?

Answer (score 0):

1)

In Xcode at the top left corner:
   Corner > iPhone 6.0 Simulator
Has to be set to 
   Corner > Yakubs Phone      (or whatever your phone name is)

2)

Click on your project name (top of file list)
Click on the Project name under PROJECT in the PROJECT/TARGETS view (small white column)
Click on Build Setting
Scroll to the Code Signing paragraph
  The values for Code Signing Entitlements shall be filled:
  Debug - Any iOS SDK "iPhone developer" id
  Release - Any iOS SDK "iPhone developer" id

These "iPhone developer" ids are as defined by yourself.